# Array with classes: Check for uniqueness

Tags: php

I have a collection of classes, and I need to filter them whether they're unique in an array.

My approach:

```
public function unique() {
    $uniqueStreams = [];

    foreach($this->streams as $stream) {
        if(!in_array($stream, $uniqueStreams)) {
            $uniqueStreams[] = $stream;
        }
    }

    return new static($uniqueStreams);
}
```

The problem is, that `in_array` only checks for the existance of that classname(at least that's what I've explored), but I need to make sure that they're not identical(it is desired that the instances are from the same class).

Comment: Doesn't `array_unique($this->streams,SORT_REGULAR)` work for you?

Comment: What are the criterias of uniqueness?

Comment: @apokryfos Yeah, that doesn't work for me. It works like I descirbed above, it only checks for an instance, but when I have different properties,  but based on the same instance, they're still not together.

Comment: @u_mulder That all properties of the instances together are unique.

Comment: You can serialize every instance and compare strings.

Comment: That's the solution @u_mulder! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As @u_mulder turned out, serializing them and compare the strings is solving the challenge!

```
public function unique() {
    $uniqueStreams = [];

    foreach($this->streams as $stream) {
        $serialized = serialize($stream);
        if(!in_array($serialized, $uniqueStreams)) {
            $uniqueStreams[] = $serialized;
        }
    }

    foreach($uniqueStreams as &$uniqueStream) {
        $uniqueStream = unserialize($uniqueStream);
    }

    return new static($uniqueStreams);
}
```